# Skip Error and Continue Function in R

Tags: r, for-loop, try-catch, histogram

I have a data set with p number of variables. I want a function that creates histograms of each variable, and when it encounters a problem it attempts to create a barplot instead. If it encounters a problem after attempting the barplot it skips that p, and continues to the next p.

What I'm thinking (pseudocode):

```
for (i in ncol(data)) {
    try( hist(data[i])) {
        if "error" try( barplot(data[i])) {
            if "error" print ("Error") }
        }
    continue to i # code executes through all columns of data
    }
}
```

I've tried using the try() and tryCatch() based on other stackoverflow posts, but I can't seem to figure out how to work it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to use `tryCatch` for this. Something like the following should do the trick (though I can't test it since you don't provide any data).

```
for(i in 1:ncol(d)) {
  tryCatch(hist(d[[i]], main=i), error=function(e) {
    tryCatch(barplot(d[[i]], main=i), error=function(e) {
      print('Error')
    })
  })  
}
```

Comment: Yes this worked. I changed one thing: barplot(table())

Sorry I couldn't provide data. I kept trying to generate dummy data and ran into errors . . . Thanks!